# wsdl2java Invalid endpoint address in port when the address exists

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I would like to connect to eBay API. I downloaded the [WSDL from their site](http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl)

I can see that the address exists:

```
<wsdl:service name="FindingService">
        <wsdl:documentation>
            <Version>1.12.0</Version>
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:port name="FindingServiceSOAPPort"
            binding="tns:FindingServiceSOAPBinding">
            <soap12:address
                xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
                location="https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

However, when I try to create a new Web Service Client project in Eclipse I get:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: 
Emitter failure.  Cannot find endpoint address in port FindingServiceSOAPPort 
in service FindingServiceLocator
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem while using `Axis` instead of `Axis2` for `wsdl2java` generation. You would have to try it with `Axis2` instead of `Axis` - earlier as well I had run into similar timeout and emitter exceptions which were to be sorted by switching to `Axis2`.

In the below example screenshots, I used your example `WSDL` and was able to generate the client classes, below:

1. Set your `Axis2` up - [download](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi) from here
2. Associate the `Axis2` runtime to the downloaded directory
   [image]
3. Create a `Dynamic Web Project` in eclipse
   [image]
4. Make sure to select a **lower** `Dynamic Web Module version` (like: 2.5 as 3.0 causes conflicts with Axis2)
   [image]
5. Select the `Web Service Client` within the created project
   [image]
6. Ensure to pick `Web service Runtime` as **Apache Axis2**
   [image]
7. Voila, you are a step away from generating your client classes!
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some issue with the URL, I see that their sandbox service is up and running at http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1. May be you can you try creating project with sandbox and see if it works, and then contact the webservice provider for actual issue.

You can try import the project in SOAP-UI, am sure the production end point URL will fail, and the sandbox will work. Looks like there is no issue with WSDL2Java tool.

Comment: Hi, thanks how do you see that the other URL is wrong? I get the same response for https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1 and the sandbox

Comment: http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?wsdl gives the descriptor information whereas svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?wsdl does not work.